# more professional scatterplot in R

Tags: r, plot, graph, graphics, scatter-plot

I want to produce the scatterplots between the first variable of a dataset and all others, e.g. from `iris` the `Sepal.Length` with all others. I have created the following:

```
data <- iris[,c(-5)]

par(mfrow = c(2, 2))
for (i in seq(ncol(data))[-1]) {
  plot(
    data[, 1],
    data[, i],
    xlab = colnames(data)[i],
    ylab = "Y"
  )
  lines(lowess(data[,1],data[,i]),col="red")
}
```

which results in: [image]

Is there any way to make it looks more professional and not so simple??

Comment: Try with `pairs(data)`

Comment: Use `ggplot2`, not base graphics.

Comment: BentonSans Book font, it's the Tableau default.

Comment: Making "professional looking" data visualization is a much bigger topic than a tool or library... granted some tools/libraries probably make it easier to do than others.  If you really want to look professional, I suggest studying at least one good text on data viz.  The Tufte books are great references.  I really enjoyed "Storytelling with Data" (Knaflic) which does a good job of digesting down the Tufte books (and others) into easily approachable steps/directions/guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ggplot2` is great for this type of thing. There are a bunch of [themes](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/ggtheme.html) that can be used to quickly create high quality plots. It also gives you a lot of flexibilty to customize your plot by changing individual elements.

In addition to being able to make the plots pretty, it is very effective at creating the plots in the first place. Here is somewhere to start :

```
library(tidyverse)

#your example data
data <- iris[, c(-5)]
#pivot_longer rearranges the data in to a long form, which makes it easier to plot
data_def <- pivot_longer(data, -Sepal.Length)

#the data to be plotted
ggplot(data_def, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = value)) +
#adding the scatter plot (each value is a point)
geom_point() + 
#adding a LOESS smoothed line (the default method of smoothing), without the standard error 
  geom_smooth(se = FALSE, color = "red", size = 0.5) +
#Splits into the three plots based on the measurements and moves the titles underneath the x-axis
  facet_wrap( ~ name, scales = "free_y", strip.position = "bottom") +
#Changes the overall look of the plot
  theme_classic() +
#Removes elements of the former title (now x-axis) so that there is no surrounding box 
  theme(strip.background = element_blank(),
        strip.placement = "outside") +
#Manually change the axis labels
  labs(x = NULL, y = "Y")
```

I also use [`ggpubr`](https://rpkgs.datanovia.com/ggpubr/) which is based on ggplot2

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Although i believe the labels are wrong. Y and x range are same as my example but labels are inverse. Furthermore, can you add comments on the functions you use?

Comment: I've added some brief annoations but it is worth reading the [ggplot2 documentation](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/index.html) to get a better idea. I switched the axis labels, but your method is a little unusual as, in your example, the x-axis labels really represent the y-axis values. The x-axis is sepal length.